# Synonyms: one-time-purchase (business model) / one-shot deal businesses

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What phrases describe a one-time purchase business plan or a one-shot business deal?

For instance: a restaurant is in Times Square, the food is atrocious but it doesn't matter because there are enough, new, transients everyday that you are sure to have enough customers (that will, obviously, never come back again).

The plan is just to get new customers, **passing customers**, and not to worry about long-term business.

What phrases are there for this type of business model?

Comment: Usually "unsuccessful". There may not be a word for it, because it's so rare that a business can survive without repeat customers.

Comment: Well, there's the one-pump chump... but that's a term meant for men who aren't worried about repeat customers.

Comment: [**Passing trade**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/passing-trade) I think is the most appropriate phrase. If any user agrees, they can post it. I may be wrong but I don't think so. P.S. 5 upvotes for a new answer on an old question gets a special badge.

Answer (score 2):

You might call such a business one that has a "[churn and burn](http://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2013/12/02/churn-and-burn-why-customer-success-needs-to-be-a-board-priority/)" business plan, though the connotation of such a name is usually quite negative.  The company's sole goal is *new customer acquisition* and it has no interest in (or ability to achieve) *customer retention*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the strategy a business has regarding the:

[customer retention rate](http://blog.clientheartbeat.com/customer-retention-rate/):

> - is the key factor to determining how good your customer service is and how quickly you can grow your business. If you can get the formula right, you can start retaining more customers, which will lead to strong business growth.

The kind of business model you are referring to is typical of touristic restaurants in hyper touristic places where client retention does not make much sense since new clients turnover is naturally very high. These restaurants clearly have **no customer retention strategies** and just focus on occasional clients often with the help of employees that try to persuade  tourists to enter.

Comment: but is there a name for this type of **business** or **business plan** or **business deal**?